# Why does incrementing not work the same for larger numbers as it does for a single digit?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, increment

```
section .bss

num1 resb 4
result resb 4


section .data


SYS_EXIT  equ 1
SYS_READ  equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDIN     equ 0
STDOUT    equ 1
INCREMENT equ 1


msg1 db 'Please enter an integer here:',0xA
len1 EQU $- msg1

msg2 db 'Your integer after being incremented is:',0xA
len2 EQU $- msg2


section .text
    global _start:

_start:
   mov eax, SYS_WRITE          ; Prompting user to enter a number.
   mov ebx, STDOUT         
   mov ecx, msg1         
   mov edx, len1 
   int 0x80  

   mov eax, SYS_READ  ; Reading users number.
   mov ebx, STDOUT
   mov ecx, num1
   mov edx, 4
   int 0x80

   mov eax, SYS_WRITE      ; Writing second message.    
   mov ebx, STDOUT         
   mov ecx, msg2 
   mov edx, len2
   int 0x80



   mov eax, [num1]   ; incrementing the user's number.
   mov ebx, INCREMENT
   add eax, ebx
   mov [result], eax



   mov eax, SYS_WRITE       ; Printing out incremented number.   
   mov ebx, STDOUT         
   mov ecx, result 
   mov edx, 4
   int 0x80
```

Just started learning basic assembly code today and I'm trying to increment user input numbers by 1. I am getting weird results when the number is any bigger than a single digit. What's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your treat your input as numbers and not as strings. When you receive your input (string), you get an (ASCII) string as your return value. Increasing the first char(digit) by `add eax, INCREMENT` (compacted) does work, because the first ASCII char value of `[num]` contained in `AL`(lowest byte of EAX) is increased by one. This happens because the ASCII value of `0` is 48 and the ASCII value of `9` is 57.

If you think you increase these 'digits', you would in fact increase their ASCII values, which works well until you reach the one-digit-limit(0-9). Increasing `9` by one would result in `:` and not `10`, as your may have expected because the ASCII value of `9` is 57 and adding one to it results in 58, which is the ASCII value of `:`.

So you would have to 'normalize' your 'numbers' before you operate on them with integer arithmetic. Transform them from ASCII strings to integer values.

Luckily for you, others have done this before you and optimized these approaches to the practical maximum. Look and search for `atoi`(ASCII to integer) and `itoa`(integer to ASCII). Then surround your arithmetical operations

```
mov eax, [num1]   ; incrementing the user's number.
mov ebx, INCREMENT
add eax, ebx
mov [result], eax
```

with these functions.

Comment: You would happen to know any beginner friendly resources available on this topic? I understand my mistakes now though. Thank you. Just not really sure how to implement the syntax of these atoi and itoa functions.

Comment: @Nick M: These kinds of questions have been asked many times on SO, but yet I haven't found an answer which is as simple as educating. But the basic principle is simple: atoi subtracts 30h from each byte and then multiplies each byte with its base 10 (1,10,100,1000,...), and itoa divides the value by 10 until the remainder is zero. However, there are many implementations. For example, the [MASM dev kit](http://www.masm32.com/) includes both.